# Windows phone xaml data binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox

I have a class Device which has an array of 4 sockets. each socket has id.

```
class Device
{   
    public String name { get; set; }        
    public Socket[] sArray = new Socket[4];        
}

class socket
{   
    public string id{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to print that all 4 id into listview's one item. each item has 5 textblocks. I can print device name using  but how to print socket id from array of socket in device?

```
<TextBlock Name="txtSocket1" Text="how to bind here socket id?"/>
<TextBlock Name="txtSocket2" Text="how to bind here socket id?"/>
<TextBlock Name="txtSocket3" Text="how to bind here socket id?"/>
<TextBlock Name="txtSocket4" Text="how to bind here socket id?"/>
<TextBlock FontSize="28" Text="{Binding Path=name}"/> //here easily I can get device name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're showing a collection of items you shouldn't be using different textboxes. You want to use a control that is designed to show collections, like the [**ItemsControl**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

When using this approach, and WPF/SilverLight in general, I recommend using the `MVVM pattern`. Here you provide a `ViewModel` with data to be shown in the View:

```
public class SocketViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Socket> Sockets { get; set; }

    public SocketViewModel()
    {
        Sockets = new List<Socket>();
    }
}
```

You fill up your data like this:

```
var viewModel = new SocketViewModel
{
    Name = "Some name";
    //This is some dummy just for demo purposes
    Sockets = YourDataBase.GetSockets();
}
```

Now you assign the viewmodel to the `DataContext` of the page, like this:

```
DataContext = viewModel;
```

In the XAML you can fetch all the data and show it on the screen. The correct XAML now should be something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding=Sockets}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

<TextBlock FontSize="28" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks dude! You have given me the perfect solution as per my need! well done! thanks again.... :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Note you should be binding to properties not fields.
Create a property 
          Public IEnumerable SocketsToBindTo
          { get {return _socketArray;}}

Then in each of text box you can bind to the property, create a converter and pass the array location number as a converter. In the converter you can use linq in the converter to do something like SocketsToBindTo.Skip(commandParameter).First() and return the name.

While I have told you the steps to get what you want. I don't think what you are doing is the right approach. If you are using a listview I would think you would just bind to the itemsource and then you just have to deal with setting your bindings on an Items template etc.